# iOS - more view controller icon color

Tags: ios

[image]

We have tabbar and a more view controller (bacuse too many icons for the tabbar) with icon and text. The icon (png) image color is black but on the device or simulator it's always gray. I would like to know how to change the icon color or transparency of the icon. Idea why?

Comment: where do you have it, how do you use it, is it image or buildin icon, is it tabbar icon or image or what. more info please

Comment: Thx, really fast response :) The icons are png-Images and we use them as tabbar icons.

Comment: I -1d your question as it is quite chaotically written. You say the the icons are black but fail to say if you mean source images or where. If the source images are black and only black, do they suddenly become grey and only on device (not simulator)?  You provided a screenshot where the icons are part of UITableViewCell (it seems). However in one of the replies above you say the icons are used for tab bar. That doesn't make much sense unfortunately and it shows as one of the repliers gave you an answer about tint colours which is useless in your case as you deal with images.

Comment: thx very usefull! ok my english is not the best but i thought its clear enough. More view controller is a part of the tab bar! So whats the point? The tabbar icons are rendered gray and dont get the color suddenly.

Comment: What's the point? Do you want to fix the tab bar icon? We need to see it. But in your original post you are showing icons inside the view controllers view..so which icons do you want to fix? Clenaup the questions and make it logical pls.

Comment: your comment: [...and it shows as one of the repliers gave you an answer about tint colours which is useless in your case as you deal with images] and thats false! when i set the tint color the selected icon is black..

Answer (score 0):

You can access the imageview of the button, and change the tintcolor.

```
imageView.tintColor = color;
```

For reference, UIButton has an imageView property

Comment: not working. its about tabbar icons i think. the icons in the normal tabbar are also gray instead black...any idea

Comment: Tab bar icons house a uibutton

Comment: ok but i thought the tint color is always for the selected/active icon. And when i change that color i can see a change but i dont know how to set a color for the non active icons [[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

Comment: tintcolor has nothing to do with active/inactive unless you make it so. As of iOS 7, tintColor is a convenient way to easily provide a theme to the app. Now you can generate plain color (black or whatever) pngs and change the color on the fly to go along with your theme

Comment: ok, i remove the tint color props...does ios7 maybe set a default tint color?

Comment: i unterstand now the tint color prop, but why are my tabbar icons gray per default?

Answer (score 0):

the solution is to provide a custom tableviewDataSource to the more view controller

in the cellForRowAtIndexPath you can change the color of the icons.

take a look at this

https://code.google.com/p/cweekly/source/browse/trunk/huateVideo/HuateVideo/ViewController/More/MoreViewController.m?r=339